# What does indexing on a connected layer do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I have been trying to understand this bit of code. I dont quite understand what a slicing operator does to a fully connected layer. Here's the code for context.

```
def generate_condition(self, embedding):
    conditions = fc(embedding, self.embedd_dim * 2, 'gen_cond/fc',activation_fn=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    mean = conditions[:, :self.embedd_dim]
    log_sigma = conditions[:, self.embedd_dim:]
    return [mean, log_sigma]
```

where fc returns:

```
return tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs, num_out, activation_fn=activation_fn, weights_initializer=w_init,reuse=reuse, scope=name)
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply splits your array. The way this layer works is that it has **one layer** that is supposed to produce 2 things: mu and sigma. You could achieve this by first having one, shared layers, and then 2 separate heads, one for mu, one for sigma. Another way to implement exactly the same thing is to have **one** head, of the size that is sum of the sizes of mu and sigma, and then just split it back into 2 things. In your case, first `self.embedd_dim` will be **interpreted** as mu, and the remaining features/neurons as log_sigma.